# Extending class-based generic views two have 2 models (SIMPLEST WAY) + template

Tags: django, django-views

I need to extend the `(generic.DetailView):` to include my second class, `PostImage`.
According to the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/),

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

should include something like this:

```
 def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['image_list'] = PostImage.objects.all()
        return context
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ImageField
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

STATUS = (          #tuple
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)   

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

views.py

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post, PostImage


# Create your views here.

class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

urls.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

Can I leave the urls unchanged?

post_detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
{% load static %}

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4  mt-3 left  top">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h1>{% block title %} {{ object.title }} {% endblock title %}</h1>
        <p class=" text-muted">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on }}</p>
        <!-- <img class="card-img-top" src= "{% url 'home' %}{{ post.image }}" alt="Card image cap"> -->
      
        <img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ post.image }}" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="Recipe Image Main">


        <p class="card-text "><pre class="recipe">{{ object.content }}</pre></p>
        {#  {% lorem 3 p %} #}
      </div>
    </div>

  {% block sidebar %} {% include 'sidebar.html' %} {% endblock sidebar %}
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Right now `post.image` returns the image in the template, however, I need `postimage.image` (basically my second class in the models) to return as well.. (doesn't work). What am I missing?.. Reading a buncha docs.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `image_list` but don't call it. You should use a for loop in your template.

```
{% for img in image_list %}
    {{ img.post }}
    {{ img.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what should the view look like?

Answer (score 1):

> Accessing method calls¶
>
> Most method calls attached to objects are also available from within
> templates. This means that templates have access to much more than
> just class attributes (like field names) and variables passed in from
> views. For example, the Django ORM provides the “entry_set” syntax for
> finding a collection of objects related on a foreign key.

Since your two models have a ForeignKey used to relate to each other. I think you can just utilize reverse lookup `_set` without adding the child model in the context. You can just call it in your templates something like this:

```
{% for post_image in post.postimage_set.all %}
    {{ post_image.image }}
{% endfor %}
```

Reference: [Django Template: Accessing Method calls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls)

Comment: what do you think of the answer below?

Comment: What do you mean by below? Are you referring to my answer?

Comment: the answer below this answer.. the ``{% for img in image_list %}`` loop

Comment: I think it will work since you already defined image_list into your context. But again, since your model are related to each other you don't have to make another query and add a new context since the initial context will already have the related child record. This will save you from querying again that saves you unnecessary usage of resources.

Comment: this is a pretty clever solution tho; it works. BUT.. I want to understand how the VIEWS work better. Please see the answer below about how the ``image_list`` is being implemented. THANKS again.

Comment: btw I removed the context def method.. It works with the simple view and no method

Comment: Because Django intentionally limits the amount of logic processing available in the template language, it is not possible to pass arguments to method calls accessed from within templates. Data should be calculated in views, then passed to templates for display.

Comment: If you have some time read this documentation - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/

That will help you understand how class-based views work.

Comment: yup reading and practicing.. but doesn't give nice examples like how to use it in a cookbook style at times (vague)